# Many to one in Smart Art

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am looking for a way to use Smart Art to represent a many to one organisational structure. I can find many way to make a diagram in which each manager is responsible for one or more employees, but nothing that makes one employee responsible to two or more managers.

Comment: Do you have the resources for a program like [Microsoft Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/)?

Comment: Nope, and I am prepared to make these graphics elsewhere. I was wondering if there was a way to do it in Smart Art. I can understand why it is impossible, though, as they seem to have adopted a bullet point paradigm. It's sad because the company that made PowerPivot has got a huge amount of my respect.

Comment: [There are some free alternatives](http://www.maketecheasier.com/5-best-free-alternatives-to-microsoft-visio/2012/01/20) that you should look at. These are probably good, but the integration into other Microsoft Office programs might be limited.

Comment: You might be able to create a [custom SmartArt layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg583880%28v=office.14%29.aspx) catering to your needs, but I guess unless you need it often drawing the shapes required manually would be easier.